# Excel OfficeScript with multiple conditional formatting rules

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have a shared spreadsheet that is accessible in Sharepoint / Teams / OneDrive.  I'm using a lot of conditional formatting. The problem is that conditional formatting is easy to overwrite and break when a lot of users are working in the same sheet, so I'm writing an Office Script to "reapply" rules that could potentially break.  I can't figure out how to include more than a single rule in the script.

When I open the spreadsheet in the Desktop App the rules are currently pretty straight forward as you can see below.  Each rule looks for a specific value and adds a little color coding to the same range.  All rules apply to the same range.

[image: Rules]

In the office script code editor I have a working script that creates a rule for any cells with a cell value of "LA" but I have 7 more values to evaluate.

For clarity of references:

- The worksheet tab name is "Attendance"
- The range $D$6:$NF$37 is a named range called "AttendanceData"

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

  const shAttendance = workbook.getWorksheet("Attendance");
  const rngAttendanceData = shAttendance.getRange("AttendanceData");
  const conditionalFormat = rngAttendanceData.addConditionalFormat(
    ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue
  ).getCellValue();

  let rule: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueRule = {
    formula1: "=\"LA\"",
    operator: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo
  };
  
  conditionalFormat.setRule(rule);
  
  let format = conditionalFormat.getFormat();
  format.getFill().setColor("#AEAAAA");
}
```

How can I include additional conditional formatting rules in the same Office Script to account for all 8 of these conditions?

Comment: Add a password so they cannot damage those cells.

Comment: In this particular application that is not possible.  User data entry overlaps across the entire range.  (It's a big calendar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add more conditional format with similar code snippet.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

    const shAttendance = workbook.getWorksheet("Attendance");
    const rngAttendanceData = shAttendance.getRange("AttendanceData");

    let conditionalFormat = rngAttendanceData.addConditionalFormat(
        ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue
    ).getCellValue();

    let rule: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueRule = {
        formula1: "=\"LA\"",
        operator: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo
    };
    conditionalFormat.setRule(rule);
    let format = conditionalFormat.getFormat();
    format.getFill().setColor("#AEAAAA");

    // Add 2nd conditional format
    conditionalFormat = rngAttendanceData.addConditionalFormat(
        ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue
    ).getCellValue();
    rule = {
        formula1: "=\"PR\"",
        operator: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo
    };
    conditionalFormat.setRule(rule);
    format = conditionalFormat.getFormat();
    format.getFill().setColor("#9C5700"); // Update as needed

}
```

---

Streamline the code using a `For` loop as shown below.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const shAttendance = workbook.getWorksheet("Attendance");
    const rngAttendanceData = shAttendance.getRange("AttendanceData");
    let condFormat: object[] = [
        ["=\"LA\"", "#AEAAAA"],
        ["=\"PR\"", "#9C5700"]
    ]
    for(let cFormat of condFormat){
        let conditionalFormat = rngAttendanceData.addConditionalFormat(
            ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue).getCellValue();
        let rule: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueRule = {
            formula1: cFormat[0],
            operator: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo
        };
        conditionalFormat.setRule(rule);
        let format = conditionalFormat.getFormat();
        format.getFill().setColor(cFormat[1]);
    }
}
```